# biml and script component and external file

Tags: biml

I have an external file that is a csharp file. The code searches through the public folders in Outlook calendar and return a calendar data based on root folder name and calendar name. The code includes for example:

```
                           #region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Common;
#endregion

/// <summary>
/// This is the class to which to add your code.  Do not change the name, attributes, or parent
/// of this class.
/// </summary>
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called once, before rows begin to be processed in the data flow.
    ///
    /// You can remove this method if you don't need to do anything here.
    /// </summary>
    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        /*
         * Add your code here
         */
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called after all the rows have passed through this component.
    ///
    /// You can delete this method if you don't need to do anything here.
    /// </summary>
    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        /*
         * Add your code here
         */
    }
byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        bool pbCancel = false;
        Uri OutlookWebAccessUri = new Uri(@"https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        try
        {
            #region create service binding

            // Create the service binding.
            ExchangeService esb = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
            esb.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password");// exchangeAccessAccount;           
            esb.Url = OutlookWebAccessUri;

            #endregion

            #region create CalendarView
            // this week --SET YOUR VIEW ON WHAT TIMELINE YOU WANT TO RETRIEVE YOUR CALENDAR DATA --
            //if no calendar data - start here
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(Variables.StartYear, Variables.StartMonth, 1);

            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(Variables.StartYear, Variables.StartMonth, DateTime.DaysInMonth(Variables.StartYear, Variables.StartMonth));


                //there is no calendar data, get all data
                startDate = new DateTime(Variables.StartYear, Variables.StartMonth, 1);

                endDate = new DateTime(Variables.StartYear, Variables.StartMonth, DateTime.DaysInMonth(Variables.StartYear, Variables.StartMonth));


            //find the root folder
            Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(esb, WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot, new PropertySet());
            FolderView view = new FolderView(100);

            SearchFilter search = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(FolderSchema.DisplayName, Variables.RootFolder); //Enter your rootfolder here that you are looking for in the public folder domain

            FindFoldersResults myFolderResults = rootfolder.FindFolders(search, view);

            foreach (Folder myFolder in myFolderResults.Folders)
            {
                foreach (CalendarFolder PublicItem in myFolder.FindFolders(view))
                {

                    string myname = PublicItem.DisplayName;

                    if (myname == Variables.CalendarName) //Enter your calendar name here within the sub folder
                    {

                        CalendarFolder PublicCalendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(esb, PublicItem.Id, new PropertySet());

                        CalendarView cPublicView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, 512);
                        cPublicView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End, AppointmentSchema.Id);
                        FindItemsResults<Appointment> findPublicItemResponse = PublicCalendar.FindAppointments(cPublicView);

                        if (findPublicItemResponse == null)
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        //get additional properties for each item returned by view, do this as view cannot return a lot of useful stuff like attendees
                        ServiceResponseCollection<ServiceResponse> addPublicProperties =
                                    esb.LoadPropertiesForItems(from Item item in findPublicItemResponse select item,
                                    new PropertySet(
                                            BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
                                            AppointmentSchema.Resources,
                                            AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees,
                                            AppointmentSchema.OptionalAttendees,
                                            AppointmentSchema.Subject,
                                            AppointmentSchema.Start,
                                            AppointmentSchema.End,
                                            AppointmentSchema.IsCancelled,
                                            AppointmentSchema.Location,
                                            AppointmentSchema.Body,
                                            AppointmentSchema.Categories
                                            ));


                        List<Appointment> additionalProperties = new List<Appointment>(addPublicProperties.Count);

                        if (addPublicProperties != null)
                        {
                            foreach (ServiceResponse currentResponce in addPublicProperties)
                            {
                                additionalProperties.Add(((Appointment)((GetItemResponse)currentResponce).Item));
                            }
                        }

                        Appointment currentAppointmentAddProps = null;

                        foreach (Appointment currentAppointment in findPublicItemResponse)
                        {
                            #region find additional properties for current Appointment

                            currentAppointmentAddProps = additionalProperties.Find(delegate (Appointment arg)
                            { return arg.Id == currentAppointment.Id; });

                            #endregion

                            OutputRecordSetBuffer.AddRow();

                            if (currentAppointmentAddProps.RequiredAttendees.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (var attendee in currentAppointmentAddProps.RequiredAttendees) //what to do if no attendee?
                                {

                                    OutputRecordSetBuffer.Attendee = attendee.Name;
                                    OutputRecordSetBuffer.ActualStartDate = currentAppointmentAddProps.Start;
                                    OutputRecordSetBuffer.ActualEndDate = currentAppointmentAddProps.End;
                                    OutputRecordSetBuffer.Subject = currentAppointment.Subject;
                                    OutputRecordSetBuffer.Location = currentAppointment.Location;

                                    OutputRecordSetBuffer.Detail.AddBlobData(GetBytes(currentAppointment.Body.Text));
                                    OutputRecordSetBuffer.DetailType = currentAppointment.Body.BodyType.ToString();
                                    OutputRecordSetBuffer.CalendarName = Variables.CalendarName;
                                    //Currently no way to return category color

                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                OutputRecordSetBuffer.ActualStartDate = currentAppointmentAddProps.Start;
                                OutputRecordSetBuffer.ActualEndDate = currentAppointmentAddProps.End;
                                OutputRecordSetBuffer.Subject = currentAppointment.Subject;
                                OutputRecordSetBuffer.Location = currentAppointment.Location;

                                if (currentAppointment.Body.Text != null)
                                {
                                    OutputRecordSetBuffer.Detail.AddBlobData(GetBytes(currentAppointment.Body.Text));
                                }


                                OutputRecordSetBuffer.DetailType = currentAppointment.Body.BodyType.ToString();
                                OutputRecordSetBuffer.CalendarName = Variables.CalendarName;
                            }


                        }
                    }

                }
            }





            #endregion





        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            ComponentMetaData.FireError(1, "Get empty calendar data for insert has error", e.Message, "", 0, out pbCancel);

        }
    }
}
```

My biml xml gets broken due to the (I think) types in the list. The ServiceResponseCollection and  List. Biml reads the tags <> as part of biml and then don't read the rest of the file as C#. How do I reference a C# file as I'd like to keep things neat and not having to post a whole lot of code into the Scriptprojects but keep it as a separate file as below.

```
 <ScriptProjects>
            <ScriptComponentProject Name="GetData">
                   <AssemblyReferences>
                    <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap" />
                    <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap" />
                    <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost" />
                    <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.TxScript" />
                    <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.dll" />
                    <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.AddIn.dll" />
                    <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Data.dll" />
                    <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Xml.dll" />
                </AssemblyReferences>

                <ReadOnlyVariables>
                     <Variable VariableName="CalendarName" DataType="String" Namespace="User"  ></Variable>
                    <Variable VariableName="RootFolder" DataType="String" Namespace="User"  ></Variable>
                    <Variable VariableName="StartMonth" DataType="Int32" Namespace="User"  ></Variable>
                    <Variable VariableName="StartYear" DataType="Int32" Namespace="User"  ></Variable>
                    <Variable VariableName="EndMonth" DataType="Int32" Namespace="User"  ></Variable>
                    <Variable VariableName="EndYear" DataType="Int32" Namespace="User"  ></Variable>
                </ReadOnlyVariables>

                <OutputBuffers>
                    <OutputBuffer Name="CalendarOutput" IsSynchronous="false">
                        <Columns>
                           <Column Name="Detail" DataType="String" ></Column>
                           <Column Name="Status" DataType="String" Length="50" ></Column>
                           <Column Name="ActualStartDate" DataType="Date" ></Column>
                           <Column Name="Attendee" DataType="String"  Length="50" ></Column>
                           <Column Name="Location" DataType="String"  Length="500"></Column>
                           <Column Name="Subject" DataType="String"  Length="255" ></Column>
                           <Column Name="ActualEndDate" DataType="Date" ></Column>
                           <Column Name="Category" DataType="String"  Length="50"></Column>
                           <Column Name="DetailType" DataType="String"  Length="50"></Column>
                           <Column Name="CalendarName" DataType="String"  Length="50"></Column>
                        </Columns>                    
                    </OutputBuffer>                                 
                </OutputBuffers>

                <Files >
                    <File Path="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
                        using System.Reflection;
                        using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
                        [assembly: AssemblyTitle("GetData")]
                        [assembly: AssemblyDescription("Get calendar data from Exchange")]
                        [assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
                        [assembly: AssemblyCompany("HCC DataServices")]
                        [assembly: AssemblyProduct("GetData")]
                        [assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright @ 2017")]
                        [assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
                        [assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
                        [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
                    </File>

                    <ExternalFile Path="main.cs"  ExternalPath="ExchangeCalendarScript.cs"/>

                </Files>
            </ScriptComponentProject>
        </ScriptProjects>


    <Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Packages>
            <Package Name="<#=PackageName#>" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey">
    <Tasks>  
    <Dataflow Name="Get Calendar data">
                        <Transformations>
                            <ScriptComponentSource Name="Get calendar data">

                               <ScriptComponentProjectReference ScriptComponentProjectName="GetData"></ScriptComponentProjectReference>
                            </ScriptComponentSource>
                        </Transformations>
    </Dataflow>
    </Tasks>
    </Package>
        </Packages>
    </Biml>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to close the `<ExternalFile Path="main.cs"  ExternalPath="ExchangeCalendarScript.cs" />`

Comment: Yip, sorry, missed out copying it. The issue is the tags in the c# file that messes with the BIML xml / tags. So it keeps asking for tags. Not sure if I should code the external path inside CData?

Comment: I think you've oversimplified the contents of your include file. Can you put together a minimal reproduction of the problem?

Comment: updated my code

Comment: That's still incomplete code. What method(s) are in this file or is the supplied code the complete contents of `ExchangeCalendarScript.cs`

Comment: updated my code

Comment: It looks like the code you pasted is still incomplete. I see no using statements nor is the opening line in a method call. The StackExchange series of sites is predicated on you, the asker, providing a minimal reproduction of your problem so that someone trying to answer it can identify the problem. Were I to use the supplied code in my external file, it will fail due to a syntax error which may or may not be the same error you ultimately have. Do not post proprietary information but do post a basic reproduction so that we can get to the root of your issue

Comment: I've updated to include full file. Thanks for your patience. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you think your Biml is failing on the reserved characters?  The Biml you have included is not complete, for example it does not specify any output buffers.  Can you please post your full Biml script?

Comment: Updated my code to fully include biml